# performance improvements for web scraping?

Tags: python, selenium

As part of a personal project, I tried coding a web scraper which accesses my instagram account to scrape through all the DMs in a given conversation.

It works quite well, to some extent; my problem is that the group conversation I'm trying to scrape is quite active and goes back to 2017 (so it has A LOT of messages), and at some point, the chromeengine just lags so much that the entire thing times out and crashes.
Is there any way that I can improve the performance? Maybe there's an entirely different way I should be doing this altogether?

```
def userlist():
    #create my selenium instance
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

    #Log into instagram
    driver.get("https://instagram.com")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("###############")
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("###############")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ')]").click()
    sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ')]").click()
    sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "aOOlW   HoLwm ")]').click()
    sleep(1)

    #go to the group convo
    driver.get("https://instagram.com/direct/inbox")
    sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//a[contains(@href, "/direct/t/###################")]').click()
    sleep(1)
    print("Verbindung zur Gruppe hergestellt!")
    print("")
    print("Beginne Auszählung, bitte etwas Geduld haben...")

    #scroll to the top to load older messages, until that isn't possible anymore - do this by checking for scrollTop > 0 every 3 seconds
    i = 1
    while int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "frMpI  -sxBV")]').get_attribute("scrollTop")) > 0:
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('frMpI  -sxBV')[0].scrollTop = 0")
        sleep(3)
        print(f"Schritt {i}...")
        print("")
        i += 1

    #add author names to a list
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, '_7UhW9  PIoXz       MMzan   _0PwGv            fDxYl')]"):
        text = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        if not re.match(".*[0-9]:.*", text):
            userslist.append(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

    print("")
```

Comment: did you try "TRY AND EXCEPT" method?

Comment: could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: NO PROBLEM I WILL EDIT THE CODE AND GIVE IT TO YOU. BUT I UNDERSTOOD THE ERROR YOU GET BECOZ OF THE TIMEOUT WHATS THE OTHER INSTAGRAM MESSAGES PROBLEM YOU ARE HAVING THAT I DID NOT UNDERSTAND.

Comment: Did you profile your code? Which part is slow? Are you aware that your code includes ``sleep(3)`` in a ``while`` loop?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i am sorry for using ALLCAPS

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, I am aware of that - the 3 second sleep is not the issue, it's just that the javascript slows down massively after loading a certain big amount of old messages

Comment: @harshjain the timeout is caused by the javascript lag, that is my only issue. I do not have any problems with instagram messages.

Comment: @Nimansky ohh then you desperately need TRY AND EXCEPT function in your code .The error occurs in while loop right?

Comment: @harshjain Yes, it crashes after about 300 iterations

Comment: @Nimansky i have posted the ans please mark it and upvote it if you find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so if your problem is in while loop try using this code with try and except.

```
while int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "frMpI  -sxBV")]').get_attribute("scrollTop")) > 0:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('frMpI  -sxBV')[0].scrollTop = 0")
        sleep(3)
        print(f"Schritt {i}...")
        print("")
        i += 1
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
        i += 0
```

this code will print the error and handle it and replay the loop automatically if the error comes so you don't need to worry just replace this loop with your while loop
hope it helps you

Comment: Oh, now I see what you meant! Thank you very much, this would indeed help to keep going no matter what, and I think I will do it this way for the time being.

Nonetheless, I'd still like to find a more performant way to do it.